# How to Return True/False For Items in One List Found in Another List

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to work on a function that will take two lists, and create a new list as long as the first, and return True or False if each item in the list is found in the second list. I am also incorporating the use of numpy in the event I want to use a large list.

I tried the below but I was unable to produce the result that I wanted. Any assistance is appreciated.

```py
import numpy as np

def a_is_in(a, b):
    list1 = np.array(a)
    list2 = np.array(b)
    if list1 in list2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    return

a = [3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13]
b = [3, 6, 7, 13]
_is_in = a_is_in(a, b)
print(_is_in)
```

```py
import numpy as np

def a_is_in(a, b):
    list1 = np.array(a)
    list2 = np.array(b)
    result = lambda list1, list2: any(i in list2 for i in list1)
    return result

a = [3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13]
b = [3, 6, 7, 10, 13]
_is_in = a_is_in(a, b)
print(_is_in)
```

The returned result I am looking for is a list that looks like this:
[True, False, False, True, False, True]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the second example, note that the `list1` and `list2` variables inside of `a_is_in` aren't being used; they are being shadowed by the arguments to the lambda.

Comment: Why are you creating NumPy arrays? Any speedup that its `__contains__` operation might provide over `list.__contains__` is going to be cancelled by the time it takes to build the array in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using numpy you can use `np.isin` function.

```
# arr1 and arr2 are your numpy arrays.
result = np.isin(arr1, arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple list comprehension and use `i in b` as the condition which will return either `True` or `False`

**First example**

```
a = [3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13]
b = [3, 6, 7, 13]
_is_in = [i in b for i in a]
print(_is_in)
# [True, False, False, False, False, True]
```

---

**Second example**

```
a = [3, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13]
b = [3, 6, 7, 10, 13]
_is_in = [i in b for i in a]
print(_is_in)
# [True, False, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do this using a simple syntax (as a beginner I prefer not to go too far).
But I think using a for loop for this can be a bit too heavy and there might be other simpler options.

```
def a_is_in(a, b):
    result =[]
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        if a[i] in b:
            result.append(True)
        else:
            result.append(False)
    return(result)
```